# Russian Language in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, cyrillic

I would like to test my application using Android Emulator. To do this, I need to send SMS in Russian. The problem is that I cannot make emulators input Russian characters.
For example, I set all the locale and language settings into Russian (locale, language, input language), but still when I'm in the SMS sending screen, I can enter only English characters (for now I use Nexus 4 emulator). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try adding a "hardware keyboard" to your emulator, could that help?

Comment: could you please describe what do you mean in more details?
As for now I set input language to Russian (in Settings), but still can enter only English letters

Comment: Try adding a hardware keyboard to your AVD if you have a Russian physical keyboard on your computer. Instructions: http://imgur.com/6Fxfmaq

Answer (score 15):

You need to add a Russian keyboard layout to the physical keyboard in your AVD and select it. Here's what the process look like in mine:

[image: adding keyboard layout to hardware keyboard]

Note that you don't need to switch the layout of your actual computer keyboard, it has to be English.

Also the dialog in the emulator says that you can switch between layouts with Ctrl+Space, but that doesn't seem to work for me for some reason, so I just do it via the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but as you noticed, only one layout can work (either english or russian, when you switch them in language settings of an emulator).